# MediaRecorder server dies when setMaxFileSize() and setMaxDuration() are used in combination

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-mediarecorder

While setting up the MediaRecorder instance and I use the setMaxFileSize and setMaxDuration functions in combination I get the message "W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died" and the recording stops. What i am trying to accomplish is to repeat the recording until max duration is reached.

When i use the methods alone they work perfectly fine. I can set a duration or file size and have the onInfoListener do a callback. Since i can do that i made a duration timer myself, this leads to problems like camera buffer errors sometimes.

Here is the code
https://pastebin.com/J4aSrEZU

```
private void prepareMediaRecorderV26() {
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();


    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(cameraResolution.getWidth(), cameraResolution.getHeight());
    Log.i(TAG, "Width:"+ cameraResolution.getWidth()+" Height:"+ cameraResolution.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

    // Save location and file
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    final File outputFile = presetRecordingFile(recordingDirectory, 1, timeStamp);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

    mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(recordingFileSize);
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(120000);

    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(cameraOrientation);


    //Todo: native max duration leads to MediaServer dying
    //mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(recordingDuration);
    //mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(recordingFileSize);

    //Listen to file size and other relevant info to continue recording

    mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        int i = 2;
        String startTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        File currentOutputFile = outputFile;
        private String TAG = "MediaRecorder info listener";

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {

            switch (what) {
                case MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING:

                    try {
                        currentOutputFile = presetRecordingFile(recordingDirectory, i, startTimeStamp);
                        mr.setNextOutputFile(currentOutputFile);
                        i++;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Log.i(TAG, "Max file size approaching");
                    break;

                case MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Max file size reached");
                    stopRecording();
                    break;

                case MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_NEXT_OUTPUT_FILE_STARTED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "OutputFile: " + currentOutputFile);
                    if (vibrationStartRecordingEnabled && vibrationStartOfEachFileEnabled) {
                        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {

            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR: "+ what);

            if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "MediaRecorder.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED");
                MainActivity.this.stopRecording();
            }
        }
    });


    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the log

```
V/Service: CREATE FOLDER: CHECK
FOLDER EXISTS: true
I/Service: onOpened
VERSION 26
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setup
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setAudioSource(5)
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setVideoSource(2)
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setParameter()
setVideoFrameRate(30)
setVideoSize(4032, 3024)
I/Service: Width:4032 Height:3024
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setVideoEncoder(2)
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setAudioEncoder(3)
W/MediaRecorder: setOutputFile: path = /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/file_20191103_132850_1.mp4
E/Media_APM :: isCalledPackage return false
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setMaxFileSize(36700160)
setMaxDuration(120000)
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setParameter()
W/MediaRecorder: prepare: mPath = /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/file_20191103_132850_1.mp4
I/MediaRecorderJNI: setOutputFile
prepare
I/MediaRecorderJNI: getSurface
I/Service: onConfigured
I/MediaRecorderJNI: start
I/MediaRecorder info listener: Max file size approaching
I/MediaRecorder info listener: OutputFile: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/file_20191103_132850_2.mp4
W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
I/Service: ERROR: 100
MediaRecorder.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SetMaxDuration() does not have all of the same functionality as SetMaxFileSize (which can be used to set a new filename for continuous chunked recording). However, if you don't need the maximum duration to be precise, you can estimate the maximum file size for a given maximum duration from your audio and video birates, plus some overhead.